# Formula to put dat within a sentence

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Assuming I have the following cells:

```
A1 - first_Name (e.g Mary) B1 - last_name (e.g Thomas) C1 - car (e.g 3) D1 - houses (e.g 1) E1 - children (e.g blank)
```

I want to create a formula which can auto populate into the following sentence:

```
Mary Thomas has car=‘3’, House=‘1’,
```

Answer (score 1):

All 3 of below equations build the exact same output seen in photo

> ```
> Option 1 =CONCATENATE(A2," ",B2," has car= ",C2,", House= ",D2,", Children= ",E2)
>
> Option 2 =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(32),1,A2:B2,"Has Car=",C2,",House=",D2,",Children=",E2)
>
> Option 3 =A2&" "&B2&" Has Car= "&C2&", House= "&D2&" ,Children= "&E2
> ```

[image]

Comment: But I do not need children= to show if it is null value